Paint Color Dilemma
I recently had my office painted in what was supposed to be “Hippopotamus Gray” and later when I bought a quart to do some touch up, it wasn’t the same color. Come to find out the quart of paint matched the swatch of Hippopotamus Gray” exactly. How can there be more than one “Hippopotamus Gray”? It’s a Kilz color, but I got it from Sherman Willams and it matched the kilz swatch exactly. I have no idea how this could have happened unless the painters never painted my walls the specific color I told them and they agreed to. How can I find fault?

Who paid for the original paint? Where is that receipt? What does it say the color is? Was it from S.W.?

New paint will look a bit different from older paint that has a chance to fade a bit and collect dust/dirt.

It's normal enough for "the same color" from "the same company" not to look exactly the same between two different purchases that this seems unlikely to be malfeasance. Fairly common to advise mixing several cans of the same color bought at the same time to avoid can-to-can differences, even. With already-pained surfaces, you should have the touch up paint color matched to what's on the walls, not a paint chip, unless the paint chip exactly matches what's on the walls.

Paints are colored by adding small amounts of various colorants. When you buy a small amount of paint, e.g. a quart rather than five gallons, then the amount of each colorant may become problematically small, e.g. one drop of eye-of-newt. Variations in drop size, or fractions thereof, mean that the same Paint Technician at the same store may not be able to make a matching color in multiple small batches.
